# Edit record from request history form by specific user

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have created a request history form by specific userName choosed from a combo box. All it works with the below code.

UserName Ticket# Req# start_date are my column fileds I placed under the details section of my form. (Also I included command button in details so I get command button displayed for my every record disaplys with the search)

Ticket# is my primary key.

Now Here is the problem, I do not have any idea to start here with vba logic. how My command button read my current record source Ticket# so that I can call "fndEdit" form.

Example:
My search of "userA" shows 10 records in the history hen how do I edit record 5th from current form to call my edit form "frmedit" of specific record.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'Set default record source of form
Const strsql = "SELECT Temp.userName,Temp.Recordcreated,Temp.[req#],Temp.[Ticket#],Temp.[start_date] FROM Temp"


Private Sub cbouser_Change()
Dim strFilterSQL As String
strFilterSQL = strsql & " Where [UserName] = '" & Me.cbouser & "' ORDER BY [Recordcreated] DESC;"

Me.RecordSource = strFilterSQL
'DoCmd.RunSQL strFilterSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are there so many sql strings? Why are you not using a subform with link master set to the user combo and link child set to the user id? Why are you using the change event, it is generally to be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code above should be in the click event of the combo box and you probably need a

```
Me.Requery
```

after you change the recordsource.

set the Default View property of the form to Continuous forms.  Place a command button in the detail section with a caption of "Edit this record"

in the click event of the button

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "EditForm", acNormal, , "RecordId=" & Me.RecordId
```